# Access vba treeview (class MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2) how select node after right mouse click

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview

Is there a way of getting the node clicked at in a class MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2 treeview, when a right mouse click event occurs?
Methods available include **TV_nodeClick(ByVal node As Object)** which clearly supplies the node clicked on, and **TV_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)** which clearly does not supply the node, but only the coordinates.
So how can I derive the node right-clicked on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself! I checked method list and found an interesting one: hitTest. This transforms x,y into a node; of course a check has to be added to see that a node has been determined.
Sample code:

```
Private Sub TV_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    If Button = acRightButton And Not (Me.TV.HitTest(x, y) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox (Me.TV.HitTest(x, y).Key)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I got around this in the past for checking whether the ctrl key was held down on the node_click event, but I like this way : )